# Pagination doesn't work on Ajax-Datatable-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, pagination, datatables, kaminari

I am trying to integrate `ajax-datatables-rails` enhanced table on **Rails 4.2** to display a list of content . While I've been able to get the basic search functionality to work, there seems to be a  `problem with the pagination`.  Irrespective of the value passed through `iDisplayStart`, the offset is ALWAYS 0 in the query. I see that the value for 'limit' is passed through `iDisplayLength` and that works fine.

I have no clue  what I missed out on. I've spend the last couple of days trying to sort this issue out, so any help or suggestion of any other way to get this to work would be highly appreciated.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails'
gem 'ajax-datatables-rails'
gem 'kaminari'
```

View

```
<table id="users-table", data-source="<%= students_path(format: :json) %>">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Reg No</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email Address</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller

```
def index 

    respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.json { render json: StudentDatatable.new(view_context) }
    end

end
```

student_database.rb

```
include AjaxDatatablesRails::Extensions::Kaminari

class StudentDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::Base
   def sortable_columns
      # Declare strings in this format: ModelName.column_name
      @sortable_columns ||=       ['student.regno','student.first_name','student.email']
  end

   def searchable_columns
      # Declare strings in this format: ModelName.column_name
      @searchable_columns ||= ['student.regno','student.first_name','student.email']
  end

  def data
    records.map do |record|
      [
        # comma separated list of the values for each cell of a table row
        # example: record.attribute,
        record.regno, 
        record.first_name, 
        record.email
      ]
    end
  end
private
  def get_raw_records
      query_result 
  end

  # ==== Insert 'presenter'-like methods below if necessary
  def query_result
    if params[:sSearch].blank?
      Student.all
    else
      wild_card_search = "%#{params[:sSearch]}%"
      Student.where("first_name like ?",wild_card_search).offset(params[:iDisplayStart]).limit(params[:iDisplayLength])
    end

  end

end
```

Screenshot:

Page 1
[image]
Page 2
[image]

As is shown in the above screenshot, the list is still of the first page even though I am suppose to be on the second page ..

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem so I changed to the original `gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'` (ajax-datatables-rails is a fork of that gem).

http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables

http://www.nikolatodorovic.com/nikolas-blog/rails-4-datatables-110-ajax

In thoose tutorials they show how to make the search by ajax to avoid loading all the records in the page.. the pagination works without problems..

Answer (score 0):

ajax-datatables-rails gem has updated. Not It is more powerful, have a look or can try [how-to](https://github.com/ajahongir/ajax-datatables-rails-v-0-4-0-how-to) sample project